# table of proportions in R taking into account unique persons

Tags: r, reshape

I have 3 people in a study. They are asked to pick up as many items of fruit as they wish. I then want to count the times each fruit was picked up and create a proportion using the number of participants as the denominator.

I have a participant id and the name of the fruit arranged in a table as below:

```
id<-c("a","a","a","b","b","c","c","c","c")
fruit<-c("apple","pear","orange","apple","grapes","apple","pear","orange","grapefruit")
data<-data.frame(id,fruit, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

#I would normally approach the problem using the tabyl function
janitor::tabyl(data,fruit)
```

The percentage includes all the values in the denominator which isnt what I want. It says 33% of people chose the apple, whereas the % I need is that 100% of the people chose the apple, 33% chose the grapes etc.

Can anyone suggest any code that calculates the percentage of each fruit using the number of participants as the denominator?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`dplyr`:

```r
library(dplyr)
data |> 
  summarise(
    n = n(), 
    percent = n() / n_distinct(data$id) * 100,
    .by = fruit
  )

#        fruit n   percent
# 1      apple 3 100.00000
# 2       pear 2  66.66667
# 3     orange 2  66.66667
# 4     grapes 1  33.33333
# 5 grapefruit 1  33.33333
```

`data.table`:

```r
setDT(data)[, .(n = .N, percent = .N / length(unique(data$id))), by = fruit]
```

Answer (score 3):

A base R option using `colMeans` + `table`

```
> rev(stack(colMeans(table(data)) * 100))
         ind    values
1      apple 100.00000
2 grapefruit  33.33333
3     grapes  33.33333
4     orange  66.66667
5       pear  66.66667
```

Answer (score 1):

```
n_participants <- length(unique(data$id))
pick_count     <- table(data$fruit)

pick_count / n_participants
#     apple grapefruit     grapes     orange       pear 
# 1.0000000  0.3333333  0.3333333  0.6666667  0.6666667
```